# IIS HTTP Error 500.19: The requested page cannot be accessed

Tags: asp.net, iis, web

i installed IIS on Windows 10 and i trying publish it. For now just on localhost. I have prepare VPN with public IP for this project. When i installed IIS, published my ASP.NET core 2.0 project and copied all files to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\irelevant25 and then created new website and tried load website localhost:5002 a get error (screenshot link below).
I looking for results for my issue on google and i tried i guess everything:

- set permission (screenshot link below)
- installed URL Rewrite
- enabled application for 32bit
- set load user profile to false

Default webpage is working but its onli html file. Web config is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\irelevant25.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
</aspNetCore> 
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I tried published website ASP.NET core 2.0 only visual studo generated, without any changes in code and same error. Thank you for ani advice.

[image: loading page error]
[image: security properties]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried publish .NET Core 2.0 app and i missed .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle. After install and restart PC everything working for me. This is guide how to install IIS for .NET Framerowk and also .NET Core application for Windows 10 and also Windows server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?tabs=aspnetcore2x